# Drupal 7 filter field current user

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've created a custom event content type in Drupal 7 with user fields of teacher and student. I would like to create a view in which the content is displayed only for the users who are either teachers or students in that content - a custom calendar.

So far, I've tried to create a filter on **Content: Teacher (field_teacher)**, using *user:uid* and *user*. I know it's a syntax problem, but I need the value to be *currentlyLoggedinUser*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a pretty simple solution - I created contextual filters on the two entity references (student and teacher), then in the section "If no default provided", I added "use currently logged in user".

I then had to write a custom module with a hook_query_alter to change the contextual filter's AND to an OR

Answer (score 1):

To get the currently logged in user uid, follow this code snippet.

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: I want to create a filter where field student = currentUser OR field teacher = currentUser.

Comment: not necessarily - that's why I can't use the author tag. For example, if the teacher creates the content, I still want both the teacher and the student to be able to see it.

Comment: Okay, en-sha2 Allah, I'll think of something and post it back here. Thanks for your patience :)... -Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Relationship To the field **Content: Teacher (field_teacher)** first and then check the filter options again to see if the one you need is now available.

Comment: You mean add a relationship in the content type, or in the view? I'm not sure what filter I need! I added the relationships of  "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity" for both student and teacher, but I'm not sure what effect that's supposed to have - it didn't change what was filtered.

Comment: @TrevorNewhook I meant add relationship in the View.  It won't change what is filtered but you should get more Filter options once you have added the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create two different displays and use the **Access** views option to filter based on the user's role?

Putting that suggestion aside: You shouldn't be using two fields to distinguish between a teacher and a student for your content type. Use a single field select list. Values would be 0 for student, 1 for teacher, as an example.

Then add that field as a **Contextual Filter**, select **Provide default value** and use **PHP Code** as the type. Use the following code to determine the role of the user and return the appropriate value:

```php
global $user;

if(in_array('student', array_values($user->roles))) {
  return 0;
} else {
  return 1;
}
```

I would recommend my first suggestion though and make use of the access based on roles.